# JS regex - get word after certain characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string which goes like this:

```
"teamA @ teamB" 2) "teamA vs. teamB"
```

I need to get word following **@** or **vs.**. How can I do this in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression like
`(?:@ |vs\. )(\w+)`

[image: with regexr.com]

The word after it will be stored in the first group. Now just use JavaScript to create the RegEx and search a text with it.

Comment: What tool did you use in that screenshot? Looks useful!

Comment: It's a really awesome website called http://regexr.com, I use it to create all of my RegEx's. The syntax highlighting and the explanation of several pieces of RegEx code is just plain awesome.